# Table joining in sql

Tags: sql

I have one table `admin`:

```
id  name   college      selection   download
---------------------------------------------
1   kriti      bv          admin    BC
2   priyanka   bv          admin    BC
```

and another table `guide`:

```
id  name     college   selection
---------------------------------
3   namrata   bv       anil
```

I want to get this result:

```
id   name     college   selection
---------------------------------
1    kriti     bv        admin
2    priyanka  bv        admin
3    namrata   bv        anil
```

Please suggest a SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`, if you need output, like you said

```
select id , name , college , selection from admin
UNION ALL
select id , name , college , selection from guide
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kritiupadhyay - You're welcome, if this is an answer for your question, please accept it.

Comment: @kritiupadhyay, I would suggest rethinking your data layout: you clearly have two identical things in several separate tables. Ideally there should be like a `user` or a `person` table with `id, name, college` and then `roles` table that would have information like whether a person that goes by some `id` is an admin or a guide.